# Oracle create user statement produces error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I copied and pasted the exact example user/schema creation script from the Oracle website and tried to create a new user as shown below:

```
CREATE USER itron
IDENTIFIED BY p455w0rd
DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_perm_01
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tbs_temp_01
QUOTA 10000M on tbs_perm_01;
```

I receive the following error:

> Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 18
>   Error report - 
>   SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

However, I don't see what could possible be wrong with the supplied password. I felt weird about supplying a password without putting quotes around it, but that's the way you do it.

Comment: which version of oracle do you use

Comment: and which tool you use for run this script

Comment: Oracle xe 11g. SqlDeveloper

Comment: it is about xe , I think there are limitations about this, can you try it on oracle 11g

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

```
SQL> create user emunna identified by 1asdas;
create user emunna identified by 1asdas 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Solution:

```
If you are using special character or start with number without double quotes 
then you will get ORA-00922 error. Please try with double quotes for the password 
starting with number or having special characters
SQL> create user emunna identified by "1asdas";
User created.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (changing tablespace names to something that exists). Maybe you are missing a space between the password and the DEFAULT keyboard when you copy/paste the query?

Comment: No. There is a newline between the password and keyword. I see it worked when I removed reference to tablespaces.

Comment: Thats strange! This worked fine: SQL> CREATE USER itron
 IDENTIFIED BY p455w0rd
 DEFAULT TABLESPACe users
 TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
 QUOTA 10000M on users;
  2    3    4    5  
User created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with Oracle SQL Developer and I get the solution with quotes:

CREATE USER "itron"
IDENTIFIED BY "p455w0rd"

But then when login, I have to write the user with the quotes but the password without the quotes:

User: "itron"
pss: p455w0rd